# VSCode autoimport not working after using absolute imports in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, auto-import

my VSCode auto import(using control + space) is not working after I created a `jsconfig.json` file in my NextJS project.

This is my json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["."]
}
```

I'm using next 10.2.3 and vscode 1.57.1. If I remove the `jsconfig.json` file, auto import works just fine..

Someone knows why?

Comment: could you please share a snap of your folder structure?

Comment: have you tried restarting your vs code? I know it's really annoying to face such issue. I keep on facing this issue regularly. Things I do to fixed it: 1) restart editor 2) have a short break if didn't work (but trust me after restarting it should work). Thank you and May your code be bug free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to add extensions as well.
Here's how my app is using it, and I'm getting auto import suggestions correctly.

```json
"baseUrl": ".",
"include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
```

Comment: The default `tsconfig` file generated by Next CLI was missing the `baseUrl` in my case. Includes were already there but auto imports didn't work without setting the `baseUrl` so if anyone else is wondering - that is probably the main culprit.

Comment: This does not work for the error the op was describing. This is for the _typescript_ config, not the js config. --- "message": "Unknown compiler option 'include'."

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when auto import stops working, I do `command palette -> reload project` and it'll be fixed. Note that "reload project" is not "reload window", it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after an update from vscode to version 1.57, I believe it's a problem in the version, because when I change it to 1.56 it works normally.

Answer (score 1):

In case you trying to auto import .js files , you need to add this : `"**/*.js"` to the include array inside tsconfig.json file